# Tag naming convention for project under test

Tags: git, testing, version-control

So, I have a test project that test 4 differents projects ( In order for the whole application to run all those project are working together).

So i want to be able to "tag" specific commit ( from the 4 differents other repo ) and be able to say that it work with a specific version of test. For example :
`Test project v1.0` work with :

`Project1 (v1.7)
 Project2 (v2.0)
 Project3 (v1.3)
 Project4 (v3.1)`

We don't use tag as of now in our Gihhub. So my questions is, is it  a good idea to tag version of other project like this for the sole purpose of telling that this specific version of the test work with those specific version. Also how should i increment the different version ?

Thank you !

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, you can mark it. 

And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If these four repositories are only works for your current project/repo**, it’s ok to tag the 4 repo to record which version of test works for certain version of your current repo. But you should change tag version format for the 4 repo in order to contain the relation with your current repo.

For example, your current repo tag version is `vx.x` (such as `v1.0`), the 4 repo tag version should be `vx.x.x.x`. The first two number to record your current version the repo test with, and the last two number to record the repo’s version you are tested. So the 4 repo’s version should be:

```
Project1 (v1.0.1.7)
Project2 (v1.0.2.0)
Project3 (v1.0.1.3)
Project4 (v1.0.3.1)
```

**If the four repositories are not only works for your current project/repo**, you’d better create a new branch and then you can tag on the new created branch.
Such as for Project1/repo1, it’s also use for other projects. So you should create a new branch `branch_currentPorejct` only for testing your current project, and then add tags on the branch if you need.